# Example implementation of Rope data structure in QTextEdit?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, qtextedit

Does anyone know an example project featuring a simple Rope data structure along with the QTextEdit widget? I'm trying to write a small and efficient text editor and understand the data structure a little better.

Comment: only one tag for your question?people are browsing questions by their tags.

Answer (score 2):

there is an example for rope in c++ included in [this](http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/~ikokkari/ccps305.html) article
or if you preffer to use something already available; check out [this](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html) link; SGI STL provides an implementation of rope.

Comment: both links are now dead :(